# Can we use Monte Carlo Markov Chain (MCMC) to simulate tennis-match outcomes, given the probability of winning any given point for each player?

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

To make the example very simple, let's say that we are given:
P(player 1 winning any point) = 0.75
P(player 2 winning any point) = 0.25
and also, to simplify, let's assume that these values remain fixed, regardless of who is serving etc.

Now it would be very straightforward to perform Monte Carlo simulations to estimate the P(player 1 winning the match).

We would simply simulate a tennis match, using the given probability values to decide who wins each point. We then simulate thousands of tennis matches to get the estimate required.

Now, would it at all be possible to somehow use MCMC to do this instead and converge faster to the required estimate?
I am mildly familiar with the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Most articles explaining MCMC talk about the application of estimating parameter values θ from the observed data D i.e. P(θ|D)
I am having difficulty figuring out what would be θ and what would be D in this example.

It seems that the probability values we are given (0.75 and 0.25) are already the parameter values θ. 
Am I right in thinking so?

Is MCMC not appropriate for this problem?

Comment: MCMC is just a Monte Carlo technique for when you know the density of a conditional distribution, and you want to simulate it.  If you know how to simulate it a different way, then MCMC is not necessarily faster (and I would guess it's slower).  In your case, I imagine the naive method to simulate is faster.  You have already picked parameters, as you said, so you wouldn't estimate them from the data.  What you're doing is not estimating a parameter, but calculating a statistic.

Answer (score 2):

> would it at all be possible to somehow use MCMC to do this instead and
>   converge faster to the required estimate?

MCMC is only there to handle target distributions that are too hard to simulate by other means. In a simple problem as the one you mention, simulation is not even necessary as the problem can be solved by analytical derivation, but if you want to implement a simulation experiment, producing a large number of Bernoulli generations is sufficient to answer the question. MCMC generally slows you down since it produces correlations between the successive simulations (the Markov part in MCMC). In the particular case you consider, namely the distribution of a sequence of Bernoulli variates with a stopping rule I do not even see how to implement an MCMC algorithm in anything but an artificial manner.

> I am mildly familiar with the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Most
>   articles explaining MCMC talk about the application of estimating
>   parameter values θ from the observed data D i.e. P(θ|D)

Furthermore, the most common use of MCMC is with Bayesian statistics and the derivation of complex posteriors, but your problem does not have a parameter θ or an observation (sample) D to start with. This tennis problem is sheer simulation for the sake of simulation, not (Bayesian) statistical inference.